# 'Stale NFS file handle' error but no NFS mount present

Tags: linux, debian, nfs

One virtual machine runnning on Xen host experienced 'Stale NFS file handle' problems and I can't explain it while there is no NFS mount present.

The problem occurs when listing the content on a specific directory:

```
$ ls -la
ls: cannot access xxx: Stale NFS file handle
```

The following command returns nothing:

```
mount -t nfs
```

Other info:

```
# cat /etc/debian_version 
5.0.3

# uname -a 
Linux abc 2.6.26-1-xen-amd64 #1 SMP Fri Mar 13 21:39:38 UTC 2009 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Conpare the contents of /etc/mtab with the output of `cat /proc/mounts`. I have that error rarely, usually I do `exportfs -r` on the NFS-Server and then remount all NFS mounts on the client.

Answer (score 1):

With no-NFS problem seems filesystem integrity. Try to check filesystem. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error comes up when client is trying to access a file or a directory which is removed/replaced.

Here are some solutions to try:

- unmount and remount: you may use `-l` option for lazy unmount
- create a new mount point
- restart nfs client
- `touch` this file, for e.g: `touch xxx`